# Ranking results from a SUMMARIZECOLUMNS operation

Tags: dax

I created the following DAX code in DAX Studio which works correctly:

```
EVALUATE
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        'Florida Sightings'[Locality Id],
        Hotspot[Subnational 1 Code],
        Hotspot[Name],
        'Calendar'[Month],

        FILTER(Hotspot, Hotspot[Subnational 1 Code] = "US-FL"),

        "Species Count", COUNTROWS(VALUES('Florida Sightings'[Common Name]))
        )
```

The output looks like this, sorted by month and species count:

[image]

I would like to take the results of the SUMMARIZECOLUMNS and add a rank column based on species count for each locality Id and month. So, for the first locality Id (L127258) and Month (1), the rank would be 1. And, for the second locality Id (L123565) and month (1), the rank would be 2 etc.

The months run from 1 through 12 for each locality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sample data to work with, I'm shooting in the dark a bit but try something along these lines:

```
ADDCOLUMNS (
    SummaryTable,
    "Rank", RANKX (
        FILTER (
            SummaryTable,
            [Locality Id] = EARLIER ( 'Florida Sightings'[Locality Id] )
               && [Month] = EARLIER ( 'Calendar'[Month] )
        ),
        [Species Count]
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your approach pretty much got me there. It doesn't quite work, but I can tweak it so that it does. What I decided to do, before your response, was to bring the results from SUMMARIZECOLUMNS into my model and then create a calculated rank field using almost the same logic as your response. But doing everything in a single step is optimal.